# Four level mixed model (multi-level linear model) - formal model specification with mathematical annotations

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multilevel-analysis

I am running a mixed-model in nlme (R) with momentary assessments (5 times, L1) nested in days (4 days, L2) nested in trimester (3 Trimester, L3) nested in participants (152, L4) from a longitudinal repeated measurement design study. I want to use the annotation to display the formal model specification using the Raudenbusch and Bryke approach (greek letters per level, mathematical annotations).

I found good examples for  three level mixed models. Unfortunately, there are no examples for four level. Does anybody know which greek letters are used for the fourth level in a multilevel model?

Comment: why not just pick an unused Greek letter you like ... ?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I was thinking that there might be conventions for the each level. Anyhow, I am sure I find an unused letter which I like :-)